# How do I mask whole cells in a Voronoi texture?

Tags: materials, procedural, masking, shader-nodes

I'm trying to overlay a Voronoi noise texture in Blender, I'd like it to blend into another texture with fewer and fewer whole cells across a gradient. I've tried two methods but neither quite gives me what I want.

Method 1: Use a gradient texture and ColorRamp

[image: Node Layout]

[image: Gradient method]

This almost works but a lot of the cells are now cut in half because they now have a gradient across them and the color ramp is just doing its job.

Method 2: Adding the gradient texture then clamping

[image]
[image]

This is much closer the effect I'm after but there some holes in the Voronoi side and some cells are still cut.

I know you can use position output of the Voronoi node to filter based on cell centre coordinates but is there any way of thresholding based on the colour at the centre of the cell?

Any ideas on how to proceed greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The effect I am trying to achieve looks very close to the bottom image but without the holes in the top of the white region.

[image]

I want to avoid the consistent horizontal cropping that occurs with the gradient texture method. I've highlighted some examples in the above image.

Comment: can u please show us a end result sketch or picture what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

you can mask out pretty easy like this:

[image]

but i have no idea how you want to blend out this to another (what texture?) and how it should look like.

But maybe this already helps you.

or do you mean like this?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I want to Blend it over another texture like the second image. Trouble is I need to control the blend with textures not position as it needs to be on a larger model more complex model.

Comment: so please improve your question with a sketch/image, how it should look like. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is this it? (the squares show the accumulated output of each node)

[image]

1. Your texture-space.. (could be UV, or Generated.. etc.)
2. Sample the texture-space at the 'Positions' of Voronoi cells
3. Sample some other texture at those positions
4. Put through a threshold to create a mask

Comment: This is ideal! I can still control the edges with a texture but using the position vector in this way allows me to control whole cells in the Voronoi.